# jquery select multiple problem

Tags: jquery

```
  <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>

    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
  </select>



 $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          alert(str);
        })
```

Its supposed to alert the option of the selected options like "Grass Dirt Bushes"

Instead i am getting blank.

Comment: By "getting blank", do you mean that the alert dialog is blank or that the code is not running at all? Because your code seems to run fine: http://jsbin.com/atiba (http://jsbin.com/atiba/edit). Are you sure you put your JavaScript in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("select").change(function () {
          var str = $(this).children('option[selected]').text();
          alert(str);
        })
});
</script>
```

No need to do it for each option, just take the relevant options as children of the select, and text() will concatenate all that match.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this with `$('select').val()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert ($("select").val());
 $("select").change(function () {
  var str = $("select").val();
  alert(str);
 })
})
</script>
```

The results are separated by commas, so the initial alert will show `Shrubs,Bushes`

Comment: Actually the result of `$('select').val()` is an array. `alert()` just calls the `toString()` method, which joins the results with a comma. So you can do `alert($('select').val().join(' '))` to duplicate the questioner's code.